# whats the worst that could happen if i run git gc --aggressive --prune every 24 hours on my git repo?

Tags: git, github

i have a repo that has constant updates from a different program,
every 20 minutes the following runs

```
git commit -m "backup `date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'`"
git pull --depth 1
git push -u origin main
```

and the .git folder size increases by around 0.1gb after each commit.
i manually ran git gc --aggressive --prune which cleared up the space and got it down from 4gb to around 1gb

is it safe to run this command every 24 hours (`git gc --aggressive --prune`),
whats the worst that could happen?

**note:** im using this as a backup system for a certain 'system'

**note2:** i have a 95mb file that i tried backing up to git-lfs, but it took quite a long time to upload it, so i switched to normal git as it was way faster.

Comment: Don't use Git for backups, use a backup solution. Besides that, the worst that could happen is your SSD wearing too fast. The repo does not care how often it is garbage-collected/repacked.

Comment: I mean, the *worst* that could happen is that the `prune` command has a subtle bug that deletes all your files, catches your server on fire, and initiates Skynet.  But in principle `git gc` isn't supposed to have visible effects on the repo.  You maybe waste some CPU cycles and wear-and-tear on the disks.  And it makes it very slightly more likely that if the system crashes unexpectedly, it may happen during your `gc` and leave your data corrupt.

Comment: knittl is there a better backup option on your mind? something linux based that has a CLI.
im using an oracle instance, so im hoping that i dont have to worry about wear and tear..

NateEldredge im hoping you mean it "could" have such a bug :s
i do have the 20 minute backups, so i can still revert in case something crazy happens,

but in general does this command do anything destructive untentionally?
i mean im not 100% familiar with the command i read up on it a lot, but im just trying to make sure that it doesnt delete anything other than garbage